# As Dapps obviously need JS how will they be accessible to visually impaired people?

Tags: dapp-development, dapps, gui

How about using screen readers or text only browsers with Dapps?
Has someone ever tried existing Dapps with this tools?
Thanks.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I don't really see opinions in this. Just say if you tried a dapp using accessibility tools and report if it worked. Only facts. If you think that saying if a dapp is accessible or not relates to opinions you're wrong. There's accessibility guidelines and checklist for web apps since a long long time ago.

Comment: @NMassart the problematic part here is where you ask if people have tried existing Dapps with these tools. Maybe you could try to improve your question by giving a specific Dapp as example and what your specific concerns are? Javascript itself might not have to be a problem anymore for the last couple years due to recommendations like [ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/)

Comment: OK, I see your point. I will try myself Dapps using these tools and see how it works and then ask. But the point is that I don't have these tools. I just feel concerned by accessibility but as someone without disabilities. That's why I expected some feedback ideally from people with vision problems. But you're right I'll try myself and come back.

Answer (score 4):

This is the same as any other web application which uses JavaScript. If your front end is HTML / JavaScript you will use the same techniques to comply with your AAA standard chosen.

For example the WAI-ARIA (Accessible Rich Internet Applications (WAI-ARIA) 1.0), as mentioned in the comments. More info: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/

Just to note, the front end does not need to be Html / JavaScript, it can be in any language which can interact with the client (.Net, Java, Ruby...), and it will follow the usual design rules for accessibility.

Comment: Except that most web site, it they're well designed and if accessibility is taken in account, could work in a degraded mode without JS and dynamic ui design. Using xhr can be replaced by full pages loading. Here we need the web3 Api and it's not for cosmetics.

Comment: Yes but these are rich web applications, not web sites, web sites are for content. How will it work soundcloud, trello, etc.. A dependency on JavaScript is not an issue.

Comment: You mean that as it's already not accessible so that's not an issue if it's still not accessible ? Or am I misreading you...

Comment: No what I meant, is that any application (regardless of front end technology) when designed correctly complies with accessibility standards.

Comment: If your frontend is in javascript/html you could follow this standard: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/ This is an interesting article also: https://www.parhamdoustdar.com/2016/04/03/tools-of-blind-programmer/